# How to send values from variables and arrays from controller to the model

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to change the script below.
where the script below is using the query "like" and "array" to find data.
I want to send these 2 variables to the model and send them back to the controller for processing.

My **Controller**:

```
    if($lewati == 0){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_fotografer WHERE spesifikasi_foto LIKE '%$kata[$i]%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            // $jml_id_filter = count($id_filter);
            // $id_filter[$jml_id_filter] = $row['id'];
            $filter_ok++;
        }
    }
```

My **Model**:

```
    function tampil_data_spesifik($kata,$i)
    {
    return  $this->db->query('select tb_fotografer WHERE spesifikasi_foto LIKE '%$kata[$i]%'');
    }
```

Comment: please can you edit a bit more details to your question to explain what you want to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0):

From codeigniter's official documentation, it's a better practice to do all `db` queries in your model and you don't need to manually type any database connection scripts.

Your controller handles incoming requests, often times from routes. For codeigniter version 3, your controller method should be

```
public function method(){

        $lewati = 0;
        $array_data = array(3, 5, 9, 4);
        $another_thing = $array_data[1] //get first item

        if($lewati === 0){
           $result = $this->model_name->method_in_model($lewati, $another_thing); //your model will accept two params
        }

        echo json_encode($result);
}
```

Then you can update your model to something like this

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Model_name extends CI_Model {

        public function method_in_model($lewati, $another_thing){
            $this->db->where('column_name', $lewati);
            $this->db->like('spesifikasi_foto LIKE', $another_thing);

             $result = $this->db->get('YOUR_TABLE_NAME');
                if(empty($result->row_array())){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
        }

    }
```

Let me know if it solved your problem already

Answer (score 0):

in your controller method

```
$this->load->model('name_of_the_model_class');
$data = $this->name_of_the_model->function_name($variable1,$variable2);
```

in your model class method

```
 //do whatever your process and return the output
 return $output;
```

Comment: thanks man. Finally, i've move my calculation to my model only.